# How to prevent custom directive on some condition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I have build a custom directive to toggle a div when clicked on a div. However I want to prevent the directive when a condition is there. Is it Possible ?

Here is my div and custom directive

```
    <div v-toggleblock="{target: '#sidebarToggle, #sidebarToggleRight, .user-dashboard, body'}">
       Show side bar
    </div>
```

The directive code is :

```
Vue.directive('toggleblock',{
    bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
            el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
             /*
                 do stuff here
             */ 

        })
    },
}
```

Comment: What does the condition depend on (i.e. where does the relevant data live)? Would you expect the directive to be responsible for disabling itself or would you expect that to be handled by the directive's consuming component?

Comment: @skirtle Condition can be anything. Lets say, based on a variable, "isToggleAllowed", if it is false than we don't want the directive to work. And yes it should be present inside the component consuming the directive